# passing value to JSP via javaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
boolean canModify   = UTIL.hasSecurity("PFTMODFY") && something;

function name() {   
      I need to pass a value false to something when the page loads.   
}
window.onLoad = name
```

How can i pass a value from JavaScript to JSP on the page load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>I *think* you mean it the other way around, have server-side code output a value that JavaScript can see at page-load time.</s>

### Sending from your server code (JSP) to your client code (JavaScript)

Just output it like you would anything else, e.g.:

```
<%
    boolean canModify   = UTIL.hasSecurity("PFTMODFY") && something;
%>
var canModify = <%=canModify%>;
//  ^              ^
//  |              +-- server-side variable
//  +-- client-side variable
```

When the JSP actually runs, the script code returned to the client will simply be

```
var canModify = false;
```

or

```
var canModify = true;
```

That's a boolean; if you need to output a string, you need to put the quotes around it and be careful that you escape anything within it that should be escaped inside a JavaScript literal string (like a backslash, for instance, and whatever quote character you're using).

### Sending from your client code (JavaScript) to your server code (JSP)

But if you *really* mean you want to send a value back to the server on page load (which seems odd, but hey), you'd have to use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) for that. If you're going to be doing Ajax stuff, I'd recommend using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) as they can dramatically simplify the process for you. For instance, using jQuery, this client-side code sends a value back to the server:

```
jQuery.get("/your/page/url", {"name": "value"});
```

(or `jQuery.post` for things that make changes). Using Prototype, it'd be:

```
new Ajax.Request("/your/page/url", {
    method:     "GET", // or, of couse, "POST"
    parameters: {"name": "value"}
});
```

All of the libs I mentioned above have similarly easy-to-use mechanisms for sending data to the server. Note that this mechanism is bound by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You don't ***need*** a library for this, of course — anything a library can do, you can do yourself. The features I've listed above are all wrappers for the `XMLHttpRequest` object ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmlhttprequest), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874%28VS.85%29.aspx), [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest)). See the linked resources for examples.

### Non-Ajax hack

I shouldn't have said you ***need*** to use Ajax for this, more like you *want* to. :-) If, for some reason, you really didn't want to use Ajax you could do it by adding something to the page with JavaScript that triggers a retrieval from the server, and then include your value as a flag in that request. For instance:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link.src = "/path/to/jsp?name=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

Your JSP would do whatever it needs to do with the query string, and then return anything that's valid in a stylesheet (`/* */`, for instance). Or if you don't want to use a style sheet link, use an `img` tag and return a transparent pixel; etc.

But **I wouldn't do that**. I'd use Ajax.

Comment: @John: Just as well I covered my bases. :-) I've striken out the other bit, and extended that bit some.