# How to access value return by javascript function into jsp scriplet tag?

Tags: javascript, jsp, scriptlet

I am new to javascript , so need your help.

I want to access a value return by javascript function into my jsp scriplet on changing a select option.my javascript function is in same jsp file.
please help me..

Comment: you can't access javascript value in jsp because javascript run on client side in your browser whereas jsp code is run on server (serverside).if you want to use value then you can try ajax

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing javascript variable value to JSP variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386984/passing-javascript-variable-value-to-jsp-variable)

Comment: What will you try ?Explain further..

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 function changeFunc() {
  if (some condition) {
   return 12;
  } else {
   return 2;
  }
 }
</script> 

and in jsp scriplet..
<%
 i want to access value return by changeFunc()
%>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant. Javascript is running on the client seide and jsp is on the server side :)

Use an ajax request to send your values to server.

Ajax.. Thats what you are looking for