# How to retrieve value from JavaScript to jsp directly?

Tags: javascript, jsp

How to retrieve value from javaScript to JSP without a form submission?

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing value to JSP via javaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021474/passing-value-to-jsp-via-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The same way for everyone, regardless of the server technology:

- GET/URL parameter
- AJAX
- Form Post

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).